# Searching a text in PDF file which is having more than 1000 pages

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

I am developing a web site. I want to search a pdf file for a search string and show the results on web site. PDF file is available and when user enter some text to search the results should be shown. I have tried with "pdf object" and that is not the thing I want to be done. My need is not to view the pdf on web site but search the pdf.

Comment: I once programmed something a little like this.  It wasn't easy.  I used Libpoppler.

Comment: Do you have any code example for what you have done

Comment: Yes, but it is complicated, and I am not sure that it will help you.  If you are running Debian, Ubuntu or the like, then retrieve the source of the `derivations` package.  My code is in there.

Comment: A better answer to your question, so that you don't have to try to decipher my old code: http://poppler.freedesktop.org/

Comment: If you need to often search the same PDF (or PDFs from a small PDF collection), you probably should extract its text and store it in some fast to search format. Especially as the searching occurs on server-side.

Comment: #mkl yes this is often accessed PDF document and its is only one.

Answer (score 1):

[Libpoppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) can help.  It parses PDF.

With Libpoppler comes the `pdftotext` command-line utility, which may suit your purpose (it comes among others in the Debian package `poppler-utils`).  Better however may be `pdfgrep`, a tool to search for text in PDF files, which does not come with Libpoppler.  All of these are available in Debian, perhaps among other places.